# How does the functor Sub act on representable Presheaves?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, functors, pullback

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a small category and Psh($\mathbb{C}$) the category of presheaves over $\mathbb{C}$. I just want to consider representable presheaves.

The funtor Sub maps a representable presheaf $h_X=\hom(-,X)$ in the subfunctor $S$ that has codomain $X$ and with the property that if $f\in S$ and for some $h$ $fh$ is defined then $fh\in S$. Is this right? Can I write it in a better way?

I also know that a subfunctor $S$ of a functor $Q$ is a class of monos, which is a class of natural transformations that are injective on every slice.

So the question is: I know that Sub maps arrows into pullbacks, but I can't understand in this case where do the natural transformation between representable presheaves go? Which is the pullback? I can do this in Set, but having functors and natural transformation I'm in trouble.

I just need to know: if $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a map between representables, what is $Sub(f)=f^*: Sub(B)\rightarrow Sub(A)$?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You mean, for example if $S \in \operatorname{Sub}(B)$, then $\operatorname{Sub}(f)(S) = f^*(S)$ is the set of $g$ with codomain $A$ such that $fg \in S$?

Comment: Please don't crosspost.

Comment: Just to clarify, is your intent that $\operatorname{Sub}$ be the subobject functor on the topos of presheaves?

Comment: Yes, but is there a better way to write the pullback? Just because I only need Sub on the representable presheaves, not all the presheaves. I can't understand where Sub maps a $h_f:h_x\rightarrow h_Y$. How can I write $f^*$?